# Terminal say command is resulting in > when pasting

Tags: terminal, command

in terminal i type say and paste my text i want my mac to say. This results in a greater than sign >. Is there a way to paste my text and get it to work?

Comment: Is there a quote (', "), a parenthesis ((, )) or some other special characters in the text you're pasting? Show it to us.

Comment: its working now thanks